# How to send parameters through AWS HTTP API to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have switched from the REST API to HTTP API for it's cost efficiency. I am a noob to AWS so please be patient with me.

**LAMBDA**

I have a simple Lambda function that returns the same value it's given. It works fine when tested from the actual Lambda console.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "hello" + event["key1"]
    };
    return response;
};
```

When the function is tested from the Lambda console with JSON input:
{ "key1":"value1" }, it returns "hellovalue1".
*This is what I want my GET/POST request to return.*

**API GATEWAY (HTTP API)**

I created a simple HTTP API which leads to the lambda function above.
https://39lzilxqm2.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/MS_APITest

When the link above is called from the browser, it returns **helloundefined**.

I would assume the way of passing an argument would be [THE LINK ABOVE]?key1=value1, but that also returns **helloundefined**

When using other online tools to send JSON data to the link above through GET/POST requests, the result is, again, **helloundefined**

Honorable mention: When sending a request through postman, it displays an error:

> CORS Error: The request has been blocked because of the CORS policy

How do I pass an argument to AWS Lambda using HTTP API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to **replicate** the issue using HTTP API. I noticed that the event has the following form.

```
{
  version: '2.0',
  routeKey: 'ANY /MS_APITest',
  rawPath: '/MS_APITest',
  rawQueryString: 'key1=value1',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    'content-length': '0',
    host: 'xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'user-agent': 'curl/7.72.0',
    'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5f5afd55-332693f425fbcc7a032809da',
    'x-forwarded-for': 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'x-forwarded-port': '443',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'
  },
  queryStringParameters: { key1: 'value1' },
  requestContext: {
    accountId: '820872329501',
    apiId: 'sg5mhha5ic',
    domainName: 'xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    domainPrefix: 'sg5mhha5ic',
    http: {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/MS_APITest',
      protocol: 'HTTP/1.1',
      sourceIp: 'xxxxxx',
      userAgent: 'curl/7.72.0'
    },
    requestId: 'SryFYjtUIAMEV5w=',
    routeKey: 'ANY /MS_APITest',
    stage: '$default',
    time: '11/Sep/2020:04:30:13 +0000',
    timeEpoch: 1599798613551
  },
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

As can be seen the `?key1=value1` is passed as

```
queryStringParameters: { key1: 'value1' },
```

Therefore, the lambda function should be:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log(event)
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "hello" + event['queryStringParameters']["key1"]
    };
    return response;
};
```

I **verified** that it works using:

```
curl https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/MS_APITest?key1=value1
```

which resulted in:

```
hellovalue1
```

Comment: This works as a charm! You solved the problem and deserve a golden medal. Your reply helped me on an unimaginable scale. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it would be up to your api gateway configuration to  properly map something - query parameters, POST or PUT body (note GET request bodies are disregarded), form data - to Json input for your lambda.  Look closely at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html - note how

> the entire request is sent to the backend Lambda function as-is, via a catch-all ANY method that represents any HTTP method. The actual HTTP method is specified by the client at run time. The ANY method allows you to use a single API method setup for all of the supported HTTP methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, and PUT.

Later they show how

```
curl -v -X POST "https://r275xc9bmd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/helloworld?name=John&city=Seattle" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "day: Thursday" -d "{ \"time\": \"evening\" }"
```

or, for a GET request,

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://r275xc9bmd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/helloworld?name=John&city=Seattle' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'day: Thursday'
```

all are captured in the catch-all configuration provided there.

However, if that integration isn't quite right, the data won't be passed properly, so look closely.

Comment: Hi I just wonder. The link provided is for REST API. Does it also apply to HTTP API? It seems that OP wants to use Lambda with HTTP API in API Gateway, not REST API.

Comment: That's right, REST API's have tons of documentation made on how to use and configure them. There is little to no documentation on HTTP API's and how to set them up. I've been searching for mapping options but found nothing. That's what bothers me.

Comment: @Ziphold HTTP API is quite new and very limited. Which explains its lower price and lack of resources and tutorials :-(