# HTTP API returns undefined value outside AWS Lambda test environment

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to pass a simple `key1` parameter through an HTTP API to my Lambda Function. When I do a test it works when I pass a simple value `{"key1": "value1"}`, however, when I use my HTTP API connected to the lambda function to make the same call using Postman, it returns `undefined` instead of `value1` like the test environment did.

My temp API: https://5fitm6ca95.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/getPresignedURLforEmailAttachments

Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "They key is " + event.key1 + ". Event console log: " + JSON.stringify(event),
    };
    return response;
};
```

I tried to add `queryStringParameters` to the event as described by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63839474/how-to-send-parameters-through-aws-http-api-to-lambda) answer but it didn't work.

UPDATE:
Below is what comes in the Postman response. I just can't figure out how to access it with my Lambda. I tried `event.body.key1` but it didn't work. Response still comes as `undefined`:

[image]

Comment: How do you call it in postman?

Comment: Have you tried `event.queryStringParameters.key1` ? instead of `event["key1"]` ?

Comment: I have tried `event.queryStringParameters.key1` and it did not work. Returned  `{"message":"Internal Server Error"}` as a response.

Comment: In Postman I use `POST` request, enter the api url and add the same `{ "key1": "value1"}` as body using raw JSON.

Comment: @Smlok I mean is this POST body payload, headers or query string parameters?

Comment: If I understood you correctly @Marcin, the post body payload is in JSON and I don't use any query string parameters.

Comment: I just added a `console.log(event)` to the API response. I can see key1 is there, just need to figure out now how to access it through the API request. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `event.queryStringParameters` to work, you need to use a GET request with a query string, not a POST request with a JSON body. Otherwise you can use `JSON.parse(event.body)`. See the tutorial at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html for details.

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the right direction. This worked for me `JSON.parse(event.body).key1`